# How to protect sub folder via .htaccess file in wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to set permission to access my beta site, but I got "Page not found" error, below is my code, how can I fix this error?

```
AuthUserFile /home3/mysitename/public_html/beta/.htpasswd
AuthName EnterPassword
AuthType Basic
<Limit GET POST>
require valid-user
```

Comment: Put your .htaccess in folder, which needs to protect.  Put your .htpasswd outside public_html, for example, /home3/mysitename/.htpasswd, and don`t forget to write path to .htpasswd into .htaccess

Comment: I have tried that, and get Page not found

Answer (score 1):

Most rules that are in htaccess files have precedence in subfolders first. Meaning a htaccess file in your /beta/ folder will completely supercedes any rules in a parent directories.

So if you need to protect only the subfolder and not the main folder place the htaccess (or the part with the password section) in the folder you wish to protect.

By the way a better idea might be to use a subdomain for that construct.

Comment: Both are different sites, so it is not possible to remove main site's htaccess file

Comment: sure, but then you need to move the password protection section from the htaccess in your main folder to the file in the subfolder.